# what is processing equivalent of p5.js textToPoints() functions for fonts?

Tags: java, processing, p5.js

https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Font/textToPoints

This function traces the boundary of the text and gives me an array of points in that boundary.

Do we have an equivalent of this in Processing or the Java API?

Comment: sorry this function does not do that.. let me update the question a bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done on a per-character basis in Processing.

**Getting the Edge Vertices of a Given Character**

```
ArrayList<PVector> edgeVertices = new ArrayList<>();

PFont font = createFont("Arial", 96, true);

PShape shape = font.getShape(char c);

for (int i = 0; i < shape.getVertexCount(); i++) {
    edgeVertices.add(shape.getVertex(i));
}
```

**Drawing an Outline from Edge Vertices**

```
strokeWeight(2);
beginShape();
for (PVector v : edgeVertices) {
    vertex(v.x + 55, v.y + 125);
}
endShape(CLOSE);
```

**Result (char = 'H', font = Comfortaa)**

[image]

Comment: where is the documentation for this? Because i was not able to search it up

Comment: As for the *font.getShape()* method, you won't find any extended docs about it. It is only named in the [javadoc](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PFont.html). *createFont()* is documented [here](https://processing.org/reference/createFont_.html).

Comment: I think this will only work for the simplest characters which have a single path. Characters like ?, i, p, j, b, %, #, etc. will all fail to render correctly.